# Python pymysql : cannot run multiple statements

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am working on a project which needs to read a input.sql file and source all the commands in it.
It was working fine for all other statements, but for procedures it is not working.

You can try to replicate it yourself using these inputs.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products( 
> Prod_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
> Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
> Price INT NOT NULL, 
>  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
>
> Insert into products(Name,Price) Values('soap',1);
> Insert into products(Name,Price) Values('toilet paper',2);
> Insert into products(Name,Price) Values('Choco taco',3);
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts() 
> BEGIN     
> SELECT * FROM products; 
> END;
> ```

But while I am executing a create procedure and call statements, I am unable to do so. Can anyone please help me out?

a few statements as below but, it is not working

> with connection.cursor() as cursor:
>
> ```
>     for statement in script.split(';'): 
>
>         if len(statement) > 0:
>
>             cursor.execute(statement + ';')
> ```

I understand that the issue is because of the ; delimiter, But how can I make sure the whole procedure gets executed?

Cursor of pymysql seems to execute one statement at a time and doesn't allow multiple execution.?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are splitting on `;`, the procedure gets executed as two separate statements:

```
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM products;
```

and

`END;`

which are both invalid SQL.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But even if I execute with a different delimiter, it shows error, how can I salvage this to make it execute for all these statements?

Comment: Can I set a delimiter inside the procedure?

Comment: The `mysql.connector` package (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python) should let you execute multiple statements at once.

Comment: Then what should I do to run a create procedure? Because I can't add a delimiter :'( since if allows only a single statement